# Check for Saved IDs in Core Data database and show/hide button “Add to Fav” in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Profile View Controller (VC1), and on this VC1 I have a button that says "Add to Favourite". When I tap this button, I am able to save this details (ID and Profile Name) in the Core Data database and able to see this data/s in the table list view inside my Fav View Controller (VC2). Now, when i go to the VC2, I can see all the favourites in the table list and when I click on one of the record, it will show me details of that Profile.

But now the problem is, The button which I have here "Add to Favourite", I need to change it **"Remove from Favourite"** as this profile is already marked as favourite.

I am able to understand the concept, that the obj ID needs to check with in the database and if there is a match then the Button.setTitle will change and do the required function. But I am not able to figure this out correctly.

Thanks for your time, really appreciate!!!

My code for saving the data

```
 @IBOutlet weak var fav_remove_fav_button_label: UIButton!


@IBAction func saveFav(_ sender: Any) {

    var proID = saved_id
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let task = FavProfile(context: context) // Link Task & Context
    task.busName = bussinessName
    task.profileID = Int32(id!)!
    print ("saved id is: - \(task.profileID)")
    print ("saved profile name is: - \(task.busName)")
    fav_remove_fav_button_label.setTitle("Remove From Favourite", for: .normal)

    // Save the data to coredata
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    // let _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Added to your Favourite list", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

my function to fetch and check the data

```
func isExist(id: Int) -> Bool {
    var error: NSError?
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FavProfile")
    if let results = try! moc.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [FavProfile] {

        if !results.isEmpty {
            for x in results {
                if x.profileID  == Int32(id) {
                    print("already exist")
                    moc.delete(x)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print(error)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Are you getting "FavProfile" according to profileID ? in bool method

Comment: return true. if you found same "profileID"

Comment: I tried both true/ false but the error i get in the output panel is:  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @VarinderSingh hi, I am still not able to get this right..

Comment: @VarinderSingh i tried to work on your example solution, but doesnt work me

Comment: have your " print("already exist")" is working ? when you are checking the data

Comment: @VarinderSingh it crashes and shows the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". So I dont get the print in the output panel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150139/discussion-between-varinder-singh-and-sarah-malik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ->

```
  func isExist(id: Int) -> Bool {

     let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var error: Error? = nil
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "FavProfile", in: context)
    fetch.entity = entityDescription
        as? NSEntityDescription!
        NSEntityDescription()
    fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "profileID == %d", id)
    let fetchedObjects: [Any]? = try? context.fetch(fetch)
    if error != nil {
        return false
    }
    else {
        if (fetchedObjects?.count)! > 0 {
              print("fetchedObjects--->found");

            return true
        }
        else {
             print("fetchedObjects--->nil");
            return false
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  //  favButtonLabel()

 //   isExist(id: 182397)

    let FavCheck: Bool = isExist(id:182397)
    if FavCheck == true {
        print("favourite--->");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.